# JavaScript Play Button 1 Starts Video for Play Button 2

Tags: javascript, html, video, onclick

I am making a webpage that has two videos on it. I want each video to play when its poster image is clicked on. To do this, I added the script below to each video, and changed the id for each to "video1" and "video2".For some reason both videos play and stop the second video. I can't see why. Below is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="fade">
<button onclick="playPause()">
<video id="video1" width="350px" height="250" poster="images/video-    
poster-2.jpg" controls>
<source src="videos/pup-head-lite-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/pup-head-lite-video.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support this video.
</video>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>   

<div class="fade">
<button onclick="playPause()">
<video id="video2" width="350px" height="250" poster="images/video-   
poster.jpg" controls>
<source src="videos/original-portable-dog-potty.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/original-portable-dog-potty.webm"  
type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support this video.
</video>
</div> 

SCRIPTS

<script> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause()
{ 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
    else 
    myVideo.pause(); 
} 

</script> 

<script> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video2"); 

function playPause()
{ 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
    else 
    myVideo.pause(); 
} 

</script>`   



NEW CODE

<div class="fade">
                  <button onclick="playPause('video1')">
                  <video id="video1" width="350px" height="250"   
poster="images/video-poster-2.jpg" controls>
                  <source src="videos/pup-head-lite-video.mp4" 
type="video/mp4">
                  <source src="videos/pup-head-lite-video.webmhd.webm" 
type="video/webm">
                  Your browser does not support this video.
                  </video>
                  </div>

                  <br/>

                  <br/> 

                  <div class="fade">
                  <button onclick="playPause('video2')">
                  <video id="video2" width="350px" height="250"   
poster="images/video-poster.jpg" controls>
                  <source src="videos/original-portable-dog-potty.mp4" 
type="video/mp4">
                  <source src="videos/original-portable-dog-potty.webm" 
type="video/webm">
                  Your browser does not support this video.
                  </video>
                  </div>


         </div>



<script> 

function playPause(video)
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video"); 
{ 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
   }else 
    myVideo.pause(); 
} 
}

</script>
```

Comment: For some reason both videos play and stop the second video. I can't see why.

Comment: it's because you're using the same variable for both functions...trying renaming myVideo to something else for the seocnd script...

Comment: any luck? I don't see any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having issues because you are using the same variable to refer to the video in both cases.  You repeated yourself a little bit in your code, so I tried to cut out those bits. Let me know if you have any issues.

```
<div class="fade">
<button onclick="playPause('video1')">
<video id="video1" width="350px" height="250" poster="images/video-    
poster-2.jpg" controls>
<source src="videos/pup-head-lite-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/pup-head-lite-video.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support this video.
</video>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>   

<div class="fade">
<button onclick="playPause('video2')">
<video id="video2" width="350px" height="250" poster="images/video-   
poster.jpg" controls>
<source src="videos/original-portable-dog-potty.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/original-portable-dog-potty.webm"  
type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support this video.
</video>
</div> 


<script> 

function playPause(video)
{ 
    var myVideo=document.getElementById(video); 
    if (myVideo.paused) {
        myVideo.play(); 
    } else { 
        myVideo.pause(); 
    }
    // you could consolidate the above if/else to be:
    // myVideo.paused ? myVideo.play() : myVideo.pause();

} 

</script>
```

Comment: Humm, can't get either to work. Nothing plays now. I'll add my re-written code beneath the old code in above. Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: looks like some brackets are off in the code you posted...try copy pasting mine

Comment: or, just try these two lines:
`var myVideo=document.getElementById(video);



myVideo.paused ? myVideo.play() : myVideo.pause();`

Comment: this is using the ternary operator...it's a simple way to make an if/else shorter:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: what fixed it for you?

Comment: My problem after you all sent the code was missing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the fact that you use the same names for everything:

```
<script>
    var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); // Creates variable myVideo

    function playPause() // Creates a function called playPause
    {
      // Plays or pauses "myVideo"
    }

</script>

<script>
    var myVideo=document.getElementById("video2"); // Overrides the value of "myVideo" to point to video2 instead

    function playPause()
    {
      // Plays or pauses "myVideo"
    }
</script>
```

So when you actually call playPause, myVideo has always been set to point to video2.

I suggest that you pass the ID of the video you want to play or pause when you call playPause, and that you only define playPause once - that second definition is totally redundant, since it's the exact same code.

```
function playPause(videoId) {
    var myVideo=document.getElementById(videoId);

    if (myVideo.paused) {
        myVideo.play();
    } else { 
        myVideo.pause();
    } 
}
```

Then your buttons can be rewritten to be

```
<button onclick="playPause('video1')">
<button onclick="playPause('video2')">
```

Comment: ...that's literally the exact same answer I posted?

Comment: It's really not, in my opinion. Your answer can be copy/pasted and used to replace the broken code. Mine has a bit more explanation of what was actually broken in the original and why the changes I suggest fix that problem. It's the difference between giving a fish and teaching to fish.

Comment: I mean the code is literally the same, minus videoId in yours to video in mine.

Comment: Well yeah, the change that fixes the problem is kind of obvious. Literally every competent software developer would come up with almost exactly that. It's a six-line function.

Comment: Sure, I guess. You could two line it if you wanted as well